# ActivityResultCallback function onActivityResult won't be triggered on some devices (Android Studio / Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I have a fragment which opens a new activity. From this activity, once the save or back button is pressed, the data in the activity is retrieved and sent back to the fragment. This is atleast, what I expect to happen. On devices where it doesnt work as expected, the new activity launches, but when returning to the fragment, the function that recieves the data, `onActivityResult` from `ActivityResultCallback`, doesn't get called. Additionally, the fragment that is shown when coming back is not the correct one. This leads me to think that the activity the the fragment is in isn't properly saved and is showing the default/first fragment. This isn't an error in the application, so there aren't any error messages.

At first I was using the deprecated `onActivityResult` from the fragment class, and tried changing that to the newer method which is using the onActivityResult method from `ActivityResultCallback`. However the problem still exists, So I doubt that this is a problem due to the API version. These are the devices I tested and which ones acted as I expected

| Phone | How it ran |
| --- | --- |
| Pixel - API 28 - Emulator | As expected |
| Pixel 2 - API 29 - Emulator | As expected |
| Moto x4 - API 28 - Real | As expected |
| Moto g7 Power - API 29 - Real | Not As expected |

I have check google's documentation for the `ActivityResultLauncher` and am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.

Here are the snippets of my code that apply to this problem.

**I have a class called `Intent` which I have used in this project which is similar to the `android.content.Intent` name. In these snippets I have used `android.content.Intent` when referring to `android.content.Intent` and `Intent` for my `Intent` class.**

##### PlanFragment.java

```
public class PlanFragment extends Fragment {       
    ...    
    ActivityResultLauncher<android.content.Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    Log.d("Cursor", "OnActivityResult");
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Log.d("Cursor", "OnActivityResultOk");
                    }
                }
            });
    ...
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        FloatingActionButton addIntent = view.findViewById(R.id.add_intent);
    addIntent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                android.content.Intent intent = new android.content.Intent(view.getContext(), AddEditIntentActivity.class);
                mStartForResult.launch(intent);
            }
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

##### AddEditIntentActivity.java

```
public class AddEditIntentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {      
    ...    
    private void saveIntent() {
        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, name);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_DESC, desc);
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE, image.trim());
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);

        int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
        if (id != -1) {
            data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
        }

        Log.d("Cursor", "SaveIntent");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
        Log.d("Cursor", "SetResult");
        onBackPressed();
        Log.d("Cursor", "backPressed");
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried replacing the `onBackPressed()` with `finish()`, but that didn't help either.

The only Log messages that appear are `SaveIntent`, `SetResult`, and `backPressed`. `OnActivityResult` and `OnActivityResultOk` only appear on devices where it works.

Can someone help me identify why this problem is occuring and how I can fix it?

Comment: If the fragment you're coming back to isn't the right one, then that sounds like an issue with your first activity, not with the Activity Result API. What is your first activity doing?

Comment: If you mean the activity the fragment opens, then, that activity lets you edit some parameters on the screen (editText, Spinner, etc.). Once the save button is pressed, an android.content.Intent is created and passed back with the selected values on the screen.

Comment: No, the _first_ activity - the one you are returning the result to.

Comment: Oh ok. There is a bottom navigation bar that has three tabs. The fragment that is shown is the first tab, but in the bottom navigation bar, the middle tab is shown to be selected (highlighted). The middle tab is where I want the activity to return to. The middle tab shows a recycler view list of my Intent objects. The first tab has three tabs views(top of screen) itself, which each show a recycler view list of a selection of the Intent objects.

Comment: Since I am in a fragment, I added all my code inside onCreateView inside my fragment class. Then once everything was done, I returned the view. Could this problem be happening because the onClickListener launches the new activity before I return the view?

Comment: You said, "Additionally, the fragment that is shown when coming back is not the correct one. This leads me to think that the activity the the fragment is in isn't properly saved and is showing the default/first fragment." - this is the root problem in your activity you need to fix. Nothing in your fragment will make any difference if you have that root problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236068/discussion-between-amruth-arunkumar-and-ianhanniballake).

Comment: Using Log messages I realized that the activity/fragments were being recreated everytime. I then thought of checking my developer options to see if Don't keep activities was on. And it turns out it was. After toggling that, It started working again! Thanks for helping me though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Log messages I realized that the activity/fragments were being recreated everytime. I then thought of checking my developer options to see if Don't keep activities was on. And it turns out it was. After toggling that, It started working again!